# Activity switching from MapActivity to Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, switch-statement

I'm trying to switch to another activity which holds tabs (Map Activity Main -> Tab Activity and backwards) like this

```
findViewById(R.id.favButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent i = new Intent(Map.this, Tabs.class);
               Map.this.startActivityForResult(i, 0);

        }});
```

and in `Tab.class` i have this just to see the layout

```
public class Tabs extends TabActivity{

    public Tabs(Context cont) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.infotab);
```

Also here is my segment manifest for the activity

```
  <activity android:name=".Tabs"
android:label="@string/app_name">

</activity>
```

but I get http://pastebin.com/48Dkn7wu these errors

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I tried starting the activity without results, tried finishing the current one, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that you should remove this constructor:

```
public Tabs(Context cont) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

or at least put super(cont); in it.

Another possibility is that you didn't follow the instructions to implement a tabbed activity. I see no tabhost or anything in your paste. Are you able to make your tabs work on their own?

Comment: I'm not able to switch to the activity and load just the simple black layout. If I do that, than putting tabs would be easy. I just want to start teh activity. I've implemented all the methods that Tab Activity has also and Activity for configuration changes(issues with the orientation changes etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setClass(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this, mapslayout.class);
      startActivity(intent);



      <uses-library
         android:name="com.google.android.maps"
         android:required="true" />**
```